# extract decimal numbers from string in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Anyone can helps me to extract decimal number from string using Ajax.

What i want to do:

Input string:

```
"Laptop,sno,67890,FAN" // This is complete input string with comma and decimal.
```

The output what i want :

```
67890 // only decimal without comma and any text.
```

I have use function of `parseInt("input");`

But it works only when the my input is start with decimal like `123,name` but if the input is not start with decimal than it does not work it gives me `NaN` in result.
Any help in this regards would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

use regular expresiion

```
var re = /\d+/;
var str = "Laptop,sno,67890,FAN";
alert (str.match(re));
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rmac58wd/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript Regular Expressions.

```
var s = "Laptop,sno,67890,FAN";
var decimals = s.match(/[0-9]+/);
```

decimals will be an array containing all the decimals in the string s.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression:

```
var str = 'Laptop,sno,67890,FAN';
var re = /(\d)+/i;
var found = re.exec(str);
console.log(found[0]);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jyn46cez/1/)